# How to let `man` utility to use `less` to display manual rather than `more`?

Tags: linux, unix, solaris

I've this Solaris 10 installation and it uses `more` to display manual content. Is there a way to make it using `less` to display manual? because `more` is really not convenient to use.

Thank you.

Comment: `man something | less`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the documented way to do it:

```
export PAGER=less
```