# Open man-page with less

Tags: command-line, solaris, less, man

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to let `man` utility to use `less` to display manual rather than `more`?](https://superuser.com/questions/458572/how-to-let-man-utility-to-use-less-to-display-manual-rather-than-more)

How can i open up the Man-page for a command with the less-editor?

Alternatively, how can i find the man-page on the harddrive

I've tried using the manpath command but that doesn't seem to exist on solaris. Maybe there is a command to search for the manpage somehow?

Comment: What Solaris release are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `man` command uses less by default. See `man man` (hehe). If yours doesn't, you could simply use a pipe like this.

```
man myCommand | less
```

Comment: On Solaris, `man` doesn't use `less` by default. It uses `more -s`.

Answer (score 7):

Just add `export PAGER=less` in your .profile or .bashrc or whatever initialization file your shell use.

MANPATH is the variable used by man to find out manual pages.

Answer (score 1):

#### In short

This should give you the path to the man page file:

```
man -d $ANY_MANPAGE 2>&1 >/dev/null|grep '^found ultimate'
```

#### Explanation

From the man page:

```
   -d, --debug
          Print debugging information.
```

So,

```
man -d $ANY_MANPAGE 2>&1 >/dev/null
```

gives you a lot of information (the remainder of the command suppresses the actual man page and redirects debugging to stdout).

#### Example output

```
$ man -d man

[...]
found ultimate source file /usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz
```

Comment: Is the `man` debugging output locale independent?

Comment: As far as the implementation found in debian and suse is concerned: yes (I've found this: `fprintf (stderr, "found ultimate source file %s\n", man_file);`).  But now that you ask, I'm not even sure whether the Solaris implementation provides a `-d` switch in the first place.

Comment: That's why I deleted my earlier answer -- apparently it didn't apply to Solaris.