# Open a protected file form within man page/less?

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, less, man

I was reading the man page for `firewalld.service` and I wanted to open up the `service.xml` from within the man page ([which I believe is less](https://superuser.com/a/482330/113848)).

I know `:e` would do the job if I had permissions, but instead I had to drop out of the man page, and use `sudo less .../service.xml`

How do I avoid this in the future?

Answer (score 2):

You can run an arbitrary command in `man`/`less` with an exclamation mark ("`!`").

Type

```
!sudo less .../service.xml
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open a new `less` session as root within your unprivileged `man` or `less`.

Comment: I can't switch between files though, can I?

Comment: @Pureferret: Not easily, no. I would just open `man` with the right privileges or use a terminal multiplexer like `byobu`.